# Why does the following limit give two answers?

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

I want to calculate

$$ \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{t^2}{\sin^2(t)}$$

and I proceed as follows

$$\stackrel{H}{=} \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{2t}{2\sin(t)\cos(t)} \implies  \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{2t}{\sin(2t)}$$

and when evaluated gives

$$\stackrel{H}{=} \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{2}{2\cos^2(t)-2\sin^2(t)} =1$$

But evaluating the other equivalent term gives

$$\stackrel{H}{=} \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{2}{2\sin(2t)\cos(2t)} $$

and that does not exist as the left hand and right hand limits are not equal.

So, what do you think?

Comment: The derivative of $\sin 2t$ is $2\cos 2t$, not $2\sin 2t\cos 2t$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott omg yes. Now, this is embarrassing. Everyone ,just move along please :$

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact that $\lim_{x-0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$ as $\sin(x)=x+o(x)$ when $x$ tends to $0$ means very small so that $\lim_{x-0}\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)^2=1$ then  $\lim_{x-0}\left(\frac{x}{\sin(x)}\right)^2=1.$